# ${r + s \choose r + s - n} = \sum_{p,q,p',q'} {r \choose p} {s \choose q}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I am fixing $m,n,r,s$ such that $m + n = r + s$ from the beginning. I have the following $4$ conditions that should be satisfied :
\begin{align*}
    r &= p + p'\\
    s &= q + q'\\
    m &= p + q\\
    n &= p' + q'
\end{align*}
And I want to show that the following equation is satisfied under the previous four conditions: $${r + s \choose r + s - n} =  \sum_{p,q,p',q'}   {r \choose p} {s \choose q}. \quad \quad \quad (**)$$

How can I show this? Could someone help me please?

**EDIT:**

I feel like this is the equation I should prove but still I do not know how to do this:

$${r + s \choose  m} = \sum_{p = 0}^m {r \choose p} {s \choose m - p}$$ but still I do not know how to prove this also.

Comment: For the edit, there's a combinatorial interpretation of the LHS where we're choosing $m$ objects from $r+s$ of them. Do you see how that's equal to the RHS, say by splitting into cases that match the binomial coefficients?

Comment: @CalvinLin What do you mean by splitting into cases that match the binomial coefficients?

Comment: @Brain To choose m objects form r+s is to choose k from r and m-k from s and sum over k

Comment: Illustrating the comment of @Koobe , let $~R~ = \{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I\}, ~S = \{a,b,c,d,e,f\}.~$  Then the number of ways of selecting $~4~$ items from $~R \cup S~$ is $$\binom{9+6}{4}.$$  This can be alternatively computed by reasoning that the number of items chosen specifically from $~R~$ must be some element $~k \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}.~$  Then, the alternative computation is $$\sum_{k=0}^4 \binom{9}{k}\binom{6}{4-k}.$$

Comment: @Koobe thanks for the clarification I loved it but I want a proof ......  should I prove it by induction or what?

Comment: @user2661923 thanks for the clarification I loved it so much but I want a proof ......  should I prove it by induction or what?

Comment: @Brain The *proof* does not have to be **Algebraic**, but can instead be based on Set Theory.  You simply take the argument that has been expressed in the comments, as applied to the general case.  This constitutes a **proof**.  That is, the mutually exclusive ways of selecting $~m~$ objects from $~(r + s)~$ objects, is by selecting only $~p~$ objects from the $~r~$ objects, and $~m-p~$ objects from the $~s~$ objects, where each value of $~p~$ from the set $~\{0,1,2,\cdots,m\}~$ constitutes a mutually exclusive situation.

Comment: Compute the coefficient of $x^m$ in the both sides of $(1+x)^{r+s} = (1+x)^r (1+x)^s$. This approach is same as in the above comment by user2661923.

Comment: Still I am confused and i do not know how to do it@luxerhia can you please provide more details in an answer below

Comment: Do all the symbols $p, p', q$ and $q'$ stand for nonnegative integers?

Comment: @luxerhia yes  that is correct